# adding images on top of the button which is on a scrollview

Tags: objective-c

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"path of XML"];
NSError *error = nil;
GDataXMLDocument *document = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSError *err=nil;
NSArray *nodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"/product_list/product[category = \"Pins & Collectibles\"]/image" error:&err]; 
NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[nodes count]];

for(int i=0;i<[nodes count]; i++)
{
    [array addObject:(NSString *)[[(NSString *)[[(NSString *)[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nodes objectAtIndex:i]] componentsSeparatedByString:@"{"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"<image>"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"</image>"] objectAtIndex:0] ]; 
}

NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

the array has all the images i need to put it on top of the button

Comment: can describe your doubt?

Comment: i have added multiple buttons on scrollview which gets generated dynamically . i want to display the image which is existed on "array" on the button.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:IMAGE_DATA] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Then make a for loop in that

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:IMAGE_DATA] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```